# Django formtools, how to set wizard_view cookie expiration date?

Tags: django, cookies, django-formtools

I am using django formtools to split a long form. I want users to have the possibility to continue filling the forms after they logout/login to the site and after closing/opening their browser. However, the cookie set by formtools has an expiration date value of Session. Therefore, if the user closes the browser the cookie is deleted and the user must start filling the form from the beginning.

Is there any way to set the cookie wizard_submissions_wizard_view in the picture below to let say the 2019-01-01?

[image]